# Relay for Auxiliary Fog lamps of 54 w (27W x 2 lamps)

Tags: motorcycle, relay

I wish to install two LED Auxiliary Fog lamps of 27w each (54 w in total), for my motorbike powered through a 12V Battery. What type (capacity) of relay should be used for this. Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 4):

54 watts at 12v equates to 4.5A. That's not a lot. Any 20A automotive relay will the job. You can get both the relay and socket for the relay at almost any parts store. Here's what a 4-post looks like:

[image]